# How do I check if a SQL Server 2005 TEXT column is not null or empty using LINQ To Entities?

Tags: linq, sql-server-2005, text, linq-to-entities

I'm new to LINQ and I'm trying to check whether a TEXT column is null or empty (as String.IsNullOrEmpty).

```
from c in ...
...
select new
        {
            c.Id,
            HasBio = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.bio)
        }
```

Trying to use the above query produces an SqlException:

```
Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of len function.
```

The SQL generated is similar to the following:

```
CASE WHEN ( NOT (([Extent2].[bio] IS NULL) OR (( CAST(LEN([Extent2].[bio]) AS int)) = 0))) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN (([Extent2].[bio] IS NULL) OR (( CAST(LEN([Extent2].[bio]) AS int)) = 0)) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
```

LEN is not applicable to TEXT columns. I know DATALENGTH should be used for them...

**How can I force LINQ to produce such thing? Or any other workaround to test if a text column is null or empty???**

Thanks!

**Update**

I came up with this

```
HasBio = c.bio.Substring(0, 1).Length > 0
```

but it's a little bit ugly though, any other options?

Comment: Why do you use TEXT data type with SQL SERVER 2005 instead of VARCHAR(MAX)?

Comment: Because I inherited the application and it was made 8 eight years ago using SQLServer2000. I might consider converting the TEXT columns to VARCHAR(MAX) if it's easy to do.

Comment: It's easy to do, just did a conversion myself last week. If it's really a text field, there's no reason not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've decided to convert the TEXT columns to VARCHAR(MAX) taking in mind the following article.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125040904/http://geekswithblogs.net/johnsperfblog/archive/2008/04/16/ntext-vs-nvarcharmax-in-sql-2005.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
powerCircuitList.Where(t => t.textProperty!= null && t.textProperty!= "")
```